# Push new commits after git rebase of branch

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have one `master` branch and a `new` branch. When I started working on the `new` branch I forgot to pull the latest commits, and was 20 commits behind `master`. I also committed a couple of changes in the `new` branch.

However, I was able to update my `new` branch with the other commits from the `master` branch by doing:

```
git checkout master
git pull --rebase
git rebase master newBranch
```

Then I solved the conflicts and my `new` branch was updated with the previous commits.

The problem is that these earlier commits are only reflected in my local version of the `new` branch. I see this when typing `git log`. When I check out the remote version, it still has the old version because I haven't commited/pushed these old commits. When I check `git status`, there is nothing to commit.

How can I get the new branch to get these old commits/changes remotely and not just locally? In other words, how can the remote version have same log/history as my local version of the new branch?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve. Do you simply want to push your changes in *new* onto the server? Do you want to merge these changes in *master* and publish those? What exactly do you want to push into your remote?

Comment: I have merged the changes from master onto my local new branch. But these changes are older than my newest commit in new. How can I push this such that the remote version of the new branch  contains the old commits from master?

Comment: Have you tried to just push them?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a master and new branch(Where you have all your commits) is created out of master branch.Now if the master branch doesn't have all the commits which are there in the central repository then we need to bring the changes from server to master branch and from master to new.
Then we need to bring the local commits on new to master and then do a push from there.
The below steps does what is said above:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout new
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge new
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to accomplish can be a bit "dangerous". You have remote branches:

- origin/master
- origin/new

and local branches

- master
- new

When rebasing the local new branch onto the newest origin/master commit, you will be rewriting history. For local work, this is not a problem. If your commits have previously been pushed to a remote, and other developers might have work derived from it, it can cause a lot of head scratching because you now have at least two versions of the same changes.

If you are 100% sure that nobody has any derived work, you can push your local new branch to the server

```
git push origin new
```

this will, however, fail because the commit you're trying to push is not a fast-forward merge from the previous origin/new commit. You will need to force the push:

```
git push origin new -f
```

The server might prevent you from performing this push, though.